# ngx-bootstrap custom date format range

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I want to custome date format picker. When I submit it become like this:

[image]

What should I do to change like this `myDate: 1-2 July 2020`.
This is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51062003-yxo2oe) demo and code as you reference.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<form #z="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave(z)" novalidate>
<input class="form-control"
           placeholder="Daterangepicker"
           (ngModel)="myDate"
           name="mydate"
           bsDaterangepicker
           [minDate]="minDate"
           [maxDate]="maxDate"
           [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY',  displayOneMonthRange: true }">
           <button  class="btn btn-normal pl-4 pr-4">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
 onSave(z: NgForm){
    console.log(z.value);
  }
```